# Adding a Sentry breadcrumb in Flutter

Tags: flutter, breadcrumbs, sentry

How can I add a [breadcrumb](https://docs.sentry.io/product/error-monitoring/breadcrumbs/) in Flutter using the `sentry` package?

The [package documentation on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry) suggests to use the `addBreadcrumb` method of `SentryClient`, but my editor (PyCharm) warns me that there is no such method.

Confusingly, the [Sentry documentation on sentry.io](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dart/enriching-events/breadcrumbs/) suggests that `addBreadcrumb` is a static method of a certain `Sentry` class. Anyway, again, my editor warns me that this class does not exist.

Some details that might be relevant:

- my `pubspec.yml` has `sentry: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'` among its dependencies
- I am using Flutter 1.22.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion is because pub.dev is showing the current stable SDK, versio 3.0.1.

Version 4 is out in preview: https://pub.dev/packages/sentry/versions/4.0.0-beta.2 which has the method you're looking for and is going to be released GA tomorrow. Docs got published already but there's a note about the stable and the prerelease:

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/

Note that there's a new package now for flutter:

https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter

It already hooks into the flutter error handler, captures native crashes, [monitor release health](https://docs.sentry.io/product/releases/health/) etc.